# how to load json data from url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create graph in angularjs. it's working fine but i don't know, how can i bind data from json url in **shipmenttracking** variable. please help me.

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'Data', function ($scope, $filter, Data) {

    // Defining app scope
    $scope.app = {}
    $scope.app.data = Data;
    $scope.app.message = "In AppCtrl";

    // Define table data
    var shipmenttracking = [{ "OrderNumber": "SA00887342", "Airwaybill": "2013-09-05 12:12:36", "Status": "Postpayment", "Elapsed": "Puma" }];


    $scope.app.shipmenttracking = shipmenttracking;

} ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get JSON object response from URL

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'Data', function ($scope, $filter, $http, Data) {

    // Defining app scope
    $scope.app = {}
    $scope.app.data = Data;
    $scope.app.message = "In AppCtrl";

    var configObject = {
        method : 'GET',
        url : '<page-name-goes-here>'
        reponseType : 'text/javascript'
        };


        $http(configObject)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.app.shipmenttracking = data;
        });

} ]);
```